# My regex "appears" to work in a tester, but not in my actual code

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

Here's my code:

```
gasprices = requests.get("insert url here")

soup = BeautifulSoup(gasprices.content)
price1 = soup.find("div", class_="sp_p")

price1list = re.search('(p[0-9])', str(price1))
```

price1 resolves to the following string:

```
< div class="sp_p">< div class="p2"></div>< div class="pd"></div>< div class="p8"></div>< div class="p1"></div></div>
```

Now, when I run this in [Pythex](http://pythex.org/), it matches `"p2"`, `"p8"`, and `"p1"` which is what I want it to do. However, when I run it in python3's regex interpreter, it only matches `"p2"`. What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will search for the first instance of the match to happen, so it won;t give you all the matches.

Instead, use [`re.findall(pattern, string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) to get all the matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """< div class="sp_p">< div class="p2"></div>< div class="pd"></div>< div class="p8"></div>< div class="p1"></div></div>"""
>>> re.search('(p[0-9])', string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdefc9ee558>
>>> re.findall('(p[0-9])', string)
['p2', 'p8', 'p1']
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'm new to regexes, and I wasn't aware of the findall method. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Besides, you can let `BeautifulSoup` do the job and find all `div`s that have a class matching `p\d+` regular expression (`p` followed by one or more digits):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="sp_p"><div class="p2"></div><div class="pd"></div><div class="p8"></div><div class="p1"></div></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'p\d+'))
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="p2"></div>, <div class="p8"></div>, <div class="p1"></div>]
```

In your case, the usage would be:

```
price1.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'p\d+'))
```